# Hide/Show Div Class on image button click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have created this JSfiddle and I am trying to hide the flashing red dot when the user clicks the big green button.

So when it is RED the blinker should be hidden.
When user clicks to GREEN blinker shows again.

http://jsfiddle.net/YC3Xu/

```
<div class="BlinkSpot">
   <img src="http://m.UploadEdit.com/b029/1394017199584.gif" name="spotdia" alt="">
</div>
</br>
</br>
<div class="id1462-FIXATION-LIGHT-OFF">
   <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/2/9/b/8/1194984775760075334button-green_benji_park_01.svg.hi.png" width="600" height="600" onclick="try{ B=(B % FIXATION.length)} catch(e) { B=1 ;FIXATION=[ 'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/2/9/b/8/1194984775760075334button-green_benji_park_01.svg.hi.png', 'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/9/1/5/2/119498475589498995button-red_benji_park_01.svg.med.png']};this.src=FIXATION[B++];">
</div>
```

**Not sure why it is not word-wrapping the code on Stack Overflow**

Comment: _"Not sure why it is not wordwrapping the code on stackoverflow"_ - Because when you format as code it's not supposed to wrap - if it did it would make it confusing as to whether line-break related errors exist or not. But you can always manually add line breaks between the attributes in your img element...

Comment: I tried using the toggle function .toggle but it was not working correctly.

Comment: $(".class").toggle();
or
$(".class").show();  $(".class").hide();

Comment: I am not able to see any output on your fiddle

Comment: so many down votes..thought i put enough information here.

Answer (score 1):

It is simplest solution using jquery; http://jsfiddle.net/5Jecm/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.id1462-FIXATION-LIGHT-OFF').click(function(){
       $('.BlinkSpot').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: +1. You beat me by about five seconds. For the OP: it would be good to move the rest of your JS out of the inline `onclick=` attribute and into the jQuery `.click()` handler.

Comment: True; there are many ways to achieve the same task; since post has jquery tag so thats why i preferred to give answer using jQuery;